# how to write unix "time" like utility

Tags: c, unix

I am new to unix and learning to write some c programs that we can execute using gcc compiler in ubuntu. question:I need to write something similar to this: "time ls" where time should be replaced by my program. I know how to write c program for this, however, I cannot understand how unix will figure out what to execute if I replace time with my utility lets say "mytime" for instance? Some background for this will really help

Comment: I recommend you get a book about Unix (or rather POSIX) systems programming, and read that. It should tell you all you need to know. I haven't read the latest edition, but I heartily recommend [Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-3rd/dp/0321637739)

Comment: You mean to ask about setting proper permissions and putting them to `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`?

Comment: look at `execlp` and friends, the ones with `p` in their name.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I will take that up seriously. I am assuming this will explain me how to write such programs as that asked originally.

Comment: Yes that book will help you understand how to create such a program, and much much more. In the long run, if you want to become good at UNIX systems programming, it's a very good investment.

Answer (score 1):

Read some good Linux programming book, perhaps [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) - a bit old, but freely downloadable.

Read also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

For time related stuff, start with [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). It explains that there are *several* notions of time. Then consider [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [gettimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), [times(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html), [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) etc...

Notice also that [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) is either a builtin command of your shell, or an external one in `/usr/bin/time`. So it is some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), whose source code you could download and study.

> I cannot understand how unix will figure out what to execute

Be aware of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (see also [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)), used by [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and in [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html). You could set your `PATH` to suit your needs. You might also be interested by [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) a command or a process is doing. Notice that shells are ordinary programs, and you can write your own one (and that is a very useful exercise). Most shells are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code you can study. [`sash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) is a very simple shell...

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I have doing some reading. One question: Is there any good read about how to invoke a c program using your own written cli? In other words, if I write "mytime ls" on linux, it should invoke my program "mytime.c"? Or am I missing out anything here?